# OpenCL program freezes when high number of kernels are launched within a loop

Tags: c, opencl, nvidia

I have a loop (about 1 billion iterations) that launches OpenCL kernels. Each kernel is executed by 1 thread, and performs a very trivial operation. The problem is that after the execution of few millions iterations the code freezes (stops) and the program does not terminate at all. It freezes in the call to clFinish(). The program does not always freeze in the same iteration.

The problem disappears if clFinish() is called once every 1000 iterations instead of being called in every iteration, so I have the feeling like the problem is that clFinish() is waiting for the end of the kernel but the kernl is killed (somehow) before clFinish() is called. Note also that when I insert many printf() calls inside the loop the problem disappears!

I get the problem when I execute the program on CPU device (on my laptop, I use AMD SDK), and I get the problem also on a machine with Nvidia Fermi GPU (Nvidia SDK and drivers, AMD SDK is also installed on that machine).

I'm checking for errors after each OpenCL API call but no error is detected.  I removed the error checking to make the code clear.

My questions:

- Is their any incorrect use of the OpenCL API below ?
- Is their any problem if a huge number of OpenCL kernels are launched simultaneously ?

The code is generated automatically by some of our tools, so please don't ask why I'm calling a kernel with only 1 thread (that is another problem and I know that such a code is not good for performance).  My goal is to understand what is the problem in the code which should run without any problem in theory.

Host code:

```
/* OpenCL initialization.  */
/* ... */
cl_mem dev_acc = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(double), NULL, &err);

for (int h0 = 1; h0 <= ni; h0 += 1)
  for (int h2 = 0; h2 < nj; h2 += 1)
    for (int h5 = 0; h5 < h2 - 1; h5 += 1) {
          size_t global_work_size[1] = {1};
          size_t block_size[1] = {1};
          cl_kernel kernel2 = clCreateKernel(program, "kernel2", &err);
          clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &dev_acc);
          clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel2, 1, NULL, global_work_size,block_size,0, NULL, NULL);
          clFinish(queue);
          clReleaseKernel(kernel2);
       }
```

Kernel code:

```
__kernel void kernel2(__global double *acc)
{
   *acc = 1;
}
```

Compilation:
gcc -O3 -lm -std=gnu99 polybench.c ocl_utilities.c symm_host.c -lOpenCL -lm -I/opt/AMDAPP/include -L/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Kernel 3.2.0-29-generic, X86_64, RAM: 2 GB

Comment: I also experienced this deadlock with nVIDIA in linux (Ubuntu). But the same code on ATI/Windows did not ocur. I solved it using pinned memory. But to tell you the truth, I never knew  what caused the problem. (driver bug I guess). Looking at the code, I would not do it that way since it is highly unefficient. But should not hang the execution.

Comment: Thanks.
Did you get the deadlock with my code ? or with your own code ?
Calling the clFinish() only once every 100 iterations solves the problem for me, but I still need to understand what is the problem.

Regarding the performance issue.  Yes sure, launching a kernel for each thread is not a good idea, but I need to understand what is the problem anyway, to make sure that I'm not making a mistake in the way the OpenCL API is called.

Comment: It turned out that the problem is caused by a Library problem.  I tried with the AMD library and it works fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, looking at your code I don't even know where to start...

However, if it comes to the OpenCL standard it should run fine. If the implementation of the library you are using is capable to handle this is the question.

The first thing you should do is check the error codes of each of your OpenCL API call. I think you are "overfilling" your command queue and get silient help screams from the OpenCL libarry that nobody hears. If you use clFinish the queue get emptied fromt time to time maybe preventing this "overfilling".

Some other things:
Is one single kernel realy what you want? OpenCL is designed to perform on SIMD architectures, meaning single instructions multiple data. So OpenCL performs best when a huge amount of threads execute the same code on different data.

You don't have to create the kerneal each time within the loop:

```
size_t global_work_size[1] = {1};
size_t block_size[1] = {1};
cl_kernel kernel2 = clCreateKernel(program, "kernel2", &err);
for (int h0 = 1; h0 <= ni; h0 += 1)
  for (int h2 = 0; h2 < nj; h2 += 1)
    for (int h5 = 0; h5 < h2 - 1; h5 += 1) {
          clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &dev_acc);
          clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel2, 1, NULL, global_work_size,block_size,0, NULL, NULL);
          clFinish(queue);

       }
clReleaseKernel(kernel2);
```

The last thing is realy your execution pattern with only one thread:

try something like that if possible (i don't know your requirements on memory and so on):

```
cl_mem dev_acc = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, ni * nj * sizeof(double), NULL, &err);

size_t global_work_size[1];
global_work_size[0] = ni;
global_work_size[1] = nj;
size_t block_size[1] = {1};
cl_kernel kernel2 = clCreateKernel(program, "kernel2", &err);

// some loop
clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &dev_acc);
clSetKernelArg(kernel2, 1, sizeof(int), &h2);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel2, 1, NULL, global_work_size,block_size,0, NULL, NULL);
```

one a kernel that looks somehow like:

```
__kernel void kernel2(__global double *acc, int h5)
{
   int h0 = get_global_id(0);
   int h2 = get_global_id(1);
   int ni = get_global_size(0);
   int nj = get_global_size(1);
   // do stuff with ni, nj, h0, h2
   if (h5 < h2)
   {
      *acc = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The code is generated automatically by some of our tools, so please don't ask why I'm calling a kernel with only 1 thread.  That seems to be stupid, but the code is not written by a human being.
The code above should run without any problem in theory, but it still does not work.  My goal is to understand what is the problem.  Regarding errors, I'm checking for errors after each kernel call, no error appears.  I just removed the error checking to make the test case clear.

Comment: @bag I just was to suggest that you post this at khronos.org forums but you already did. I realy think that this is a library issue. can you test your code on a third OpenCL implementation (e.g., Intel's or pocl?)

Comment: It turned out that the problem is caused by a Library problem.  I tried with the AMD library and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

kronos has some great feedback, just to add some more input:

1. A kernel can be loaded and compiled once and used multiple times per a device.  Compilation takes some time, so it is best to do it once at the beginning.
2. When starting out in OpenCL, it is best to think of 1 thread as one iteration of a for loop.
3. To handle iteration through for loops, use `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(...)` in 1, 2, or 3 dimensions.
4. [I
   always treat my OpenCL memory as 3D, since it is easier to convert
   3D to 1D than it is 1D to 3D (for me at least).  Please see my
   linked answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954147/how-do-you-flatten-image-coordinates-into-a-1d-array/17955090#17955090)